# Length of angle bisector in a regular polygon?

Tags: geometry, relations

How can I find a relation describing the length of angle bisector of regular polygon expressed as a function of its side's length?

For a equilateral triangle and a square with a side of length $a$, the relations are:

$t_{a} = \frac{a \sqrt{3}}{2}$

and

$t_{a} = \frac{a \sqrt{2}}{2}$

Could this be generalised to relation describing bisector's length of a regular $N-$ polygon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The radius of a regular polygon with $n$ sides of length $a$ is $a/\left(2\sin{180^\circ\over n}\right)$ while its apothem is $a/\left(2\tan{180^\circ\over n}\right)$. If $n$ is even, then the bisector $d$ is twice the radius, while if $n$ is odd $d$ is the sum of radius and apothem. This leads to:
$$
d={a\over\sin(180°/n)},\ \hbox{if $n$ is even;}\qquad
d={a\over2}{1+\cos(180°/n)\over\sin(180°/n)},\ \hbox{if $n$ is odd.}
$$

Answer (score 0):

I can find the length of a bisector of a polygon using, for example, the *Cosine Law* and knowing all the angles (two of them are half the angle of the polygon and the third is found form the total sum of $180^{\circ}$) and a side of the isosceles triangle formed by any two bisectors and one of the sides of the regular polygon. But it look ugly:

$b = \sqrt\frac{a}{2(1 - \cos({180(1 -\frac{n  -2}{n}})))}$ ,

where $a-$ the side of the polygon, $b-$ the length of the bisector and $n-$ the number of the sides.

There should be something less complex. Additionally I've tried figuring out some pattern by knowing the bisector length of a square ($\frac{a\sqrt{2}}{2}$) along with that of a equilateral triangle, but nothing comes along.